# Read CSV file with comma within fields in Python

Tags: python, csv

I need to read a CSV file which has fields that have a comma, so I have double quoted the fields which contains commas, such as:

```
1, "text1,text2", "text3, text4", a, b, c
```

But when I try to read the file in Python I get the fields separated by the commas, as following:

```
row[0] = 1
row[1] = text1
row[2] = text2
row[3] = text3
row[4] = text4
row[5] = a
row[6] = b
row[7] = c
```

I am reading the CSV file with the following code:

```
info = csv.reader(open('./info.csv'))  
for row in info :
    print row[0] + " * " + row[1] ...
```

Is it possible to read double quoted  fields which contains a comma?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Python `csv` module actually does support quoted fields, even by default.  Your problem here is that Python by default does not skip the space, so you need to use `skipinitialspace=True`.

```
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO('1, "text1,text2", "text3, text4", a, b, c')
>>> list(csv.reader(s, skipinitialspace=True))
[['1', 'text1,text2', 'text3, text4', 'a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: `csv.Sniffer().sniff(s).__dict__` would indicate it too:
`{'__doc__': None,
 '__module__': 'csv',
 '_name': 'sniffed',
 'delimiter': ',',
 'doublequote': False,
 'lineterminator': '\r\n',
 'quotechar': '"',
 'quoting': 0,
 'skipinitialspace': True}`

Comment: idk how but you should be paid for this answer.. :D thanks Sven Marnach this just solved my problem.. God bless you

Comment: @AssadAli Thanks for the kind words. I'm glad this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `DictReader` on the file content.

The result looks like this

```py
import csv

with open(file_name, mode ='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
  # reading the CSV file
  csvFile = csv.DictReader(file)
  # displaying the contents of the CSV file
  for line in csvFile:
    print(line["myAttribute"]
```