# Ambiguity in parsing csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file with the following contents:

```
# country,title1,title2,type
GB,Fast Friends,Burn Notice, S:4, E:2,episode,
SE,The Spiderwick Chronicles,"SPIDERWICK CHRONICLES, THE",movie,
```

The expected output is:

```
['SE', 'The Spiderwick Chronicles', '"SPIDERWICK CHRONICLES, THE"', 'movie']
['GB', 'Fast Friends', 'Burn Notice, S:4, E:2', 'episode']
```

The problem is, the commas in the 'title' fields are not escaped. I tried using `csvreader` as well as doing string and regex parsing, but was unable to get unambiguous matches.

Is it possible  at all to parse this file accurately with unescaped commas on half of the fields? Or, does it require that a new csv be created?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj please see updates

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: read CSV file with comma within fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311900/python-read-csv-file-with-comma-within-fields)

Comment: how `Burn Notice, S:4, E:2` appears as a single field?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal that's not a duplicate, those are items enclosed within quotation marks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj -- yes, that is the title.

Comment: what's the expected output for `GB,Fast,Friends,four,Burn Notice, S:4, E:2,episode,` ? How i differentiate that this part comes under title 1 and this part comes under title 2?

Comment: @David542 if your value which contains commas is not enclosed in quotes, it will be treated as separated cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to play a trick if you can make the assumption that all commas will appear in `title2`. Otherwise, you have ambiguous data.

```
strings = ['SE,The Spiderwick Chronicles,"SPIDERWICK CHRONICLES, THE",movie,'
          ,'GB,Fast Friends,Burn Notice, S:4, E:2,episode,'
          ]
for string in strings:
    xs = string.split(',')
    country = xs[0]
    title1  = xs[1]
    title2  = ' '.join(xs[2:-2])
    mtype   = xs[-2]
    print [country, title1, title2, mtype]
```

Output:

```
['SE', 'The Spiderwick Chronicles', '"SPIDERWICK CHRONICLES  THE"', 'movie']
['GB', 'Fast Friends', 'Burn Notice  S:4  E:2', 'episode']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx (`import re`) - [see documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Match for `(\".*\",)|(.*,)`

This way you're looking either for [quoted string,] or [any string,].

Answer (score 0):

If there are commas in the fields, I would save the excel as text file with fields separated by tab.