# csv.reader removing commas within quoted values

Tags: python, csv

I have two programs that I converted to using the csv module in Python 2.7. The first I just used csv.reader:

```
f=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
line=csv.reader(f)
for values in line:
  …do some stuff…
```

In this case commas within quoted string are removed. Another program was too complex just to read so I copied the file changing the delimiter to semi-colon:

```
fin=open(sys.argv[1],'rb')   
lines=csv.reader(fin)
with open('temp.csv','wb') as fout:
  w=csv.writer(fout,delimiter=';')
  w.writerows(lines)
```

In this case the commas inside of quoted string are preserved. I find no posts on bugs.python.org on this, so I conclude it must be me. So, anyone else experience this behavior. In the second case all elements are quoted. In the first case quotes are used only where required.

Comment: Please add a few lines of your input file to your question so we can try to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without seeing a sample of your input file and the resulting output, but maybe this is related: [Read CSV file with comma within fields in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311900/python-read-csv-file-with-comma-within-fields)

Try `csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)`.