# How to split a line on comma, ignoring commas within quotes?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a file with many lines like so:

```
1,50,"asasd",25
2,51,"apa,asdfi",26
.....
.....
```

How do I split the second line by comma skipping the comma inside the string inside the double quotes?

I need the result for second line as :

```
[2,51,"apa,asdfi",26]
```

Currently I am trying:

```
x = line.split(',')
```

The result is like :

```
['2','51','"apa','asdfi"','26']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in comment, try to read your file as a .csv, it will do great with the coma inside the string.
If you have trouble using it, you can read the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html orsee some examples there https://dzone.com/articles/python-101-reading-and-writing

```
import csv

with open(file.csv,'r') as f:
    spamreader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in spamreader:
        # a row is a list containing all elements in a line
        print row
```

result:

```
['1','50','"asasd"','25']  
['2','51','"apa,asdfi"','26']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also extract them with `re.findall`:

```
>>> s = '2,51,"apa,asdfi",26'
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+|".*")', s)
['2', '51', '"apa,asdfi"', '26']
```

Though I do recommend the method mentioned in the [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311900/python-read-csv-file-with-comma-within-fields)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
line = '2,51,"apa,asdfi",26'
result = line.split(",")

length = len(result)
for i in range(length):
    if '"' in result[i]:
        result[i] += "," + result[i+1]
        result.remove(result[i+1])
        break

length = len(result)
for i in range(length):
    if result[i].isdigit():
        result[i] = int(result[i])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 51, '"apa,asdfi"', 26]
```