# python csv to tsv: in case record has comma inside

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to convert csv format to tsv.
I just used this to change comma to tab.

`tsv = re.sub(',', '\t', csv)`

But I can't deal with the string with comma inside, for example:

```
dept_no,dt,hello
1,20180411,hello its me
2,20180412,here has tab
3,20180412,"here, is, commas"
```

Is there any way to convert to tsv without affecting comma inside of the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read CSV file with comma within fields in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311900/read-csv-file-with-comma-within-fields-in-python)

Comment: You should use the csv module to parse the file - it has this and other corner cases covered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following, `csv`  module should take care of inline commas.

```
import csv
csv.writer(file('output.tsv', 'w+'), delimiter='\t').writerows(csv.reader(open("input.csv")))
```

**EDIT-1**
[Added open method as per discussion]

Insted of using `file` where we are calling constructor directly, you can use `open` which is preferred way as per [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file).
Result is same.

```
csv.writer(open('output.tsv', 'w+'), delimiter='\t').writerows(csv.reader(open("input.csv")))
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: `file('output.tsv', 'w+')` or `open('output.tsv', 'w+')` ?

Comment: Either is workable. `open` calls `file` internally as per documentation here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file. However `open` is preferred way by popularity.

Comment: Thank you so much!