# Unable to read data from CSV file and store in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Context:
Building a simple stock maintainer, using CSV file to store and read data.

Data in stock file:

```
product 1,"[200, 35.5, 37.0]"
```

```
products = {}

with open("stock.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        products[line[0]] = line[1]
        print(line)
        print(products)
```

Gives error:

```
products[line[0]] = line[1]  
IndexError: list index out of range  
['product 1', '[200, 35.5, 37.0]']  
{'product 1': '[200, 35.5, 37.0]'}
```

Comment: The two print commands at the end are just to check and find the source of error.

Comment: Depending on the platform you might need to open the file in binary mode - see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: There is nothing wrong in what you have. May be your data was not right when you tried it. Try to create a the data file again.

Comment: Can you check if there is an empty line in the stock.csv file or add a print statement print(line) before the products[line[0]] = line[1]

Comment: @meowgoesthedog that doesn't work.

Comment: @Manumathew I did what you suggested, while trying to find the source of error myself. Upon printing the line before using its indices as key:value, the data store does get printed as a list. output >>>['product 1', '[200, 35.5, 37.0]']  followed by IndexError

Answer (score 1):

In Python, arrays are zero-indexed 
(ie: `line[0]` is the first element, `line[1]` is the second, etc..) 
In here: `products[line[0]] = line[1]`, you're trying to access the second element of `line`, but from your example, the `csv` file only contains a single line, hence the error.

Comment: In the question, user is trying to access first & second elements of first line and not trying to access a second line.

Comment: line[0] is the name of the product while line[1] is the details stored as a list in the CSV file. Both are accessing just the first data row from the CSV file. Please refrase/Check. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The data in your stock file only has one line:

> product 1,"[200, 35.5, 37.0]"

So when you try to get line[1] in line 7, you are trying to get the data in line 2 of your data, which doesn't exist.

Comment: In the question, user is trying to access first & second elements of first line and not trying to access a second line.

Comment: What I am trying to do using the 'for line' loop is get the each row from the CSV file as a list. Later, I am using that list to access the actual data (with the name as 0th Index and details list as 1st index). And I am unable to find the error in doing so myself.

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311951/717882)

what you are missing is

> skipinitialspace=True

in your csv_reader.

Here is the code that worked :

```
p = {}
with open("stock.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in csv_reader:
            p[line[0]] = line[1]
    print(p)
```

and the result:

```
{'product 1': '[200, 35.5, 37.0]'}
```

Comment: For some reason, whatever combination of list indices I use >>> p[line[0]] = line[1] or >>> p[line[0]] = p[line[0], the error still exists (list index out of range)